# How to fix bad address error in MIPS assembly

Tags: sorting, assembly, mips, spim

I am very new to MIPs programming and have been struggling alone to solve to problem. I am in need of help from people of expertise, to help me through the way.

I am trying to build a program that takes in multiple integer inputs from the console and sort it through mergesort.

The problem is, though I believe logic is right, I keep on facing "Bad address in data/stack read: Ox...." error in the merge phase of the logic.

It would be of great help if you could help.
Thank you in advance.

```
.data
array: .space 40    # store max up to 10 elements integer array
eol:    .asciiz "\n"
mess: .asciiz " Enter 10 numbers to be stored in the array. "

# Some test data
eight:  .word   8
five:   .word   5
four:   .word   4
nine:   .word   9
one:    .word   1
seven:  .word   7
six:    .word   6
ten:    .word   10
three:  .word   3
two:    .word   2

# An array of pointers (indirect array)
length: .word   10  # Array length
info:   .word   seven
    .word   three
    .word   ten
    .word   one
    .word   five
    .word   two
    .word   nine
    .word   eight
    .word   four
    .word   six


    .text
main :
    la  $t0, 0
    jal readInput
    la  $a0, array      # Load the start address of the array
    lw  $t0, length     # Load the array length
    sll $t0, $t0, 2     # Multiple the array length by 4 (the size of the elements)
    add $a1, $a0, $t0   # Calculate the array end address
    jal mergesort       # Call the merge sort function
#   b   sortend         # We are finished sorting
    b   prdone


readInput :
    slt $t1, $t0, 40
    beq $t1, 1, readInputLoop
    jr  $ra

readInputLoop :
    beq $t0, 40, readInput

    # Printout the message for input
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, mess
    syscall

    # Receive inputs from the user
    li  $v0, 5
    syscall
    sw  $v0, array($t0)

    li  $v0, 1
    lw  $a0, array($t0)
    syscall

    # Increment the loop index by 4, and loop again
    addi    $t0, $t0, 4
    b   readInputLoop



##
# Recrusive mergesort function
#
# @param $a0 first address of the array
# @param $a1 last address of the array
##
mergesort:

    addi    $sp, $sp, -16       # Adjust stack pointer
    sw  $ra, 0($sp)     # Store the return address on the stack
    sw  $a0, 4($sp)     # Store the array start address on the stack
    sw  $a1, 8($sp)     # Store the array end address on the stack

    sub     $t0, $a1, $a0       # Calculate the difference between the start and end address (i.e. number of elements * 4)

    ble $t0, 4, mergesortend    # If the array only contains a single element, just return

    srl $t0, $t0, 3     # Divide the array size by 8 to half the number of elements (shift right 3 bits)
    sll $t0, $t0, 2     # Multiple that number by 4 to get half of the array size (shift left 2 bits)
    add $a1, $a0, $t0       # Calculate the midpoint address of the array
    sw  $a1, 12($sp)        # Store the array midpoint address on the stack

    jal mergesort       # Call recursively on the first half of the array

    lw  $a0, 12($sp)        # Load the midpoint address of the array from the stack
    lw  $a1, 8($sp)     # Load the end address of the array from the stack

    jal mergesort       # Call recursively on the second half of the array

    lw  $a0, 4($sp)     # Load the array start address from the stack
    lw  $a1, 12($sp)        # Load the array midpoint address from the stack
    lw  $a2, 8($sp)     # Load the array end address from the stack

    jal merge           # Merge the two array halves

mergesortend:               

    lw  $ra, 0($sp)     # Load the return address from the stack
    addi    $sp, $sp, 16        # Adjust the stack pointer
    jr  $ra         # Return 

##
# Merge two sorted, adjacent arrays into one, in-place
#
# @param $a0 First address of first array
# @param $a1 First address of second array
# @param $a2 Last address of second array
##
merge:
    addi    $sp, $sp, -16       # Adjust the stack pointer
    sw  $ra, 0($sp)     # Store the return address on the stack
    sw  $a0, 4($sp)     # Store the start address on the stack
    sw  $a1, 8($sp)     # Store the midpoint address on the stack
    sw  $a2, 12($sp)        # Store the end address on the stack

    move    $s0, $a0        # Create a working copy of the first half address
    move    $s1, $a1        # Create a working copy of the second half address

mergeloop:

    lw  $t0, 0($s0)     # Load the first half position pointer
    lw  $t1, 0($s1)     # Load the second half position pointer
###### SOURCE LOCATION OF THE PROBLEM #####
    lw  $t0, 0($t0)     # Load the first half position value
    lw  $t1, 0($t1)     # Load the second half position value

    bgt $t1, $t0, noshift   # If the lower value is already first, don't shift

    move    $a0, $s1        # Load the argument for the element to move
    move    $a1, $s0        # Load the argument for the address to move it to
    jal shift           # Shift the element to the new position 

    addi    $s1, $s1, 4     # Increment the second half index
noshift:
    addi    $s0, $s0, 4     # Increment the first half index

    lw  $a2, 12($sp)        # Reload the end address
    bge $s0, $a2, mergeloopend  # End the loop when both halves are empty
    bge $s1, $a2, mergeloopend  # End the loop when both halves are empty
    b   mergeloop

mergeloopend:

    lw  $ra, 0($sp)     # Load the return address
    addi    $sp, $sp, 16        # Adjust the stack pointer
    jr  $ra         # Return

##
# Shift an array element to another position, at a lower address
#
# @param $a0 address of element to shift
# @param $a1 destination address of element
##
shift:
    li  $t0, 10
    ble $a0, $a1, shiftend  # If we are at the location, stop shifting
    addi    $t6, $a0, -4        # Find the previous address in the array
    lw  $t7, 0($a0)     # Get the current pointer
    lw  $t8, 0($t6)     # Get the previous pointer
    sw  $t7, 0($t6)     # Save the current pointer to the previous address
    sw  $t8, 0($a0)     # Save the previous pointer to the current address
    move    $a0, $t6        # Shift the current position back
    b   shift           # Loop again
shiftend:
    jr  $ra         # Return

sortend:                # Point to jump to when sorting is complete


# Print out the indirect array
    li  $t0, 0              # Initialize the current index
prloop:
    lw  $t1,length          # Load the array length
    bge $t0,$t1,prdone          # If we hit the end of the array, we are done
    sll $t2,$t0,2           # Multiply the index by 4 (2^2)
    lw  $t3,array($t2)          # Get the pointer
    lw  $a0,0($t3)          # Get the value pointed to and store it for printing
    li  $v0,1               
    syscall                 # Print the value
    la  $a0,eol             # Set the value to print to the newline
    li  $v0,4               
    syscall                 # Print the value
    addi    $t0,$t0,1           # Increment the current index
    b   prloop              # Run through the print block again
prdone:                     # We are finished
    li  $v0,10
    syscall
```

Expected result would be printed integers of a sorted array, but i keep on receiving the error message of

> "Exception occurred at PC=0x0040015c   Bad address in data/stack read:
>   0x00000000".

Comment: Which instruction is at address 40015c? (I tried to count, but ...)

Comment: "lw $t0, 0($t0)  # Load the first half position value"

It is inside third instruction inside "mergeloop : " section

Comment: Sounds like a null pointer dereference to me. When you're executing ```lw $t0, 0($t0)```, you're overwriting whatever pointer was in $t0 with the value at that address. Is that intentional?